# Order in a asp "For To Next", how?

Tags: ms-access, for-loop, asp-classic

Is there any way to sort the order in a "For-loop"?

Or

it is possible to sort the columns(fields) if you only have only one row in an access database?

*Below is my code I'm working with.

ColumnA1, ColumnA2, ColumnA3 etc.  contains only numbers, and it is the fields I want to sort.*

Grateful for answers

```
    <%

If obj2RS.EOF Then
Else
Do While not obj2RS.EOF

For x = 1 To 40
response.write("" & obj2RS("columnA" & x & "") & ", ")
response.write("" & obj2RS("columnB" & x & "") & "")
Next

objRS.MoveNext
Loop
End if


    %>
```

Comment: looks like homework? what did you try till now

Comment: Your code will read the columns in order, so what is your question?

Comment: why you cannot make sorting on database side? in sql query